# Reverse usermod nologin Action On Sole User

Tags: login, gnome-terminal, users

I accidentally used `usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin username` on the only user on Ubuntu. Now, when I open terminal, it says “This account is currently not available” and I can’t type anything in.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the folloing steps.

First restart your PC, wait for the GRUB menu to appear(similar to this)[image: grub menu]

Now, select the **Advanced option for Ubuntu** and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>
There will be two options, select the option to go to recovery mode.

Now you will be present with different options of recovery mode. Now you have to  choose **Root Drop into root shell prompt**

You need to have write access to the `root` partition. By default, it has only read-only access using the command

```
mount -rw -o remount /
```

Now, list all the users that are present in the system

```
ls /home
```

Use the command

```
usermod --unlock <username>
```

where `<username>` is the user from the list whose password is to be reset. The `usermod` command modifies the system account.

Then exit the root shell prompt by typing `exit`

When you exit, you will be back to the recovery mode menu. Select `resume` for normal boot option.